# Without calling a class abstract can we implement few (not all) methods from interface?

Tags: java, abstract-class

Suppose we have an interface with 10 methods but only implement 5 of them in a class. Then that class should be abstract. Is there any way to implement such a class without making it abstract?

Comment: *"but is there anyway without calling a class abstract"*  Not really.  Why not 'call a spade a spade'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A class with an incomplete implementation must be declared abstract. It cannot be directly instantiated, but it can serve as a common base for subclasses to build upon.

The point of all this is that the compiler can make sure that when a method is called on an object (as defined by the interface), the method actually exists. That is part of Java's strong typing approach.

Java does have the notion of "optional methods", but this is rather informal: You have to provide a dummy implementation that throws a UnsupportedOperationException.

Answer (score 1):

If a class Implements an interface, it **guarantees** that all the methods in the interface will be implemented. That said, if you don't want to define the contents of the method, you can always just throw an UnsupportedOperationException:

```
public void cats(){
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

In short, no there is no cop out way of not declaring a method defined in an interface that you implement. But there are ways around it, however informal those may be.

Comment: btw this isn't what we made up. It's actually used in the API with Iterator.remove() (see docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You must implement all interface methods. If your class is abstract, whoever creates a concrete subclass must implement the methods.